# Start download PDF file automatically

Tags: php

I want to download PDF file automatically. It is downloading but it is giving "Failed to load PDF document."

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM `success-stories` where id='$id'";
       $result = $conn->query($select);
       $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
       $file=$row["download_pdf"];
       $file_arr=explode("/",$file);
       $path=$file_arr[0]."/".$file_arr[1]."/".$file_arr[2];
       $pdf_file=$file_arr[2];
      //  echo $file."<br/>";
      //  print_r($path);
      //  die;
       if(file_exists($path))
       {
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$path."");
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        readfile($path);
       }
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this? "Failed to load PDF document" is not part of the given code

Comment: I have fetched file from database and file is downloaded,but when open the file into browser it  is not opening and giving Failed to load PDF document

Comment: What do you mean by "giving"? Is that your browser telling you that the document could not be loaded, or any PDF viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$path."");
```

to

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
```

As mentioned by `@kmoser` in the comments, as a safety measure, you can do `htmlentities()` on the `basename()` if you are actually saving the uploaded file as is with the same name. So it would look like:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.htmlentities(basename($path)).'"');
```

Comment: I'd add `htmlentities( basename( $path ) )` to be safe.